# eclipse.buildScript Complete Example Script for headless build

Tags: eclipse, ant

I am trying to generate a build script for a plugin outside the IDE

Below is mybuild.xml

```
<project name="com.foo.poo"  xmlns='antlib:org.apache.tools.ant'>
<target name="build.plugin">
<antcall target="generateBuildScript" />
<ant dir="${workspace.dir}/${project.name}"
antfile="build.xml"
target="build.update.jar" />
<copy todir="${eclipse.dir}/plugins">
<fileset dir="${workspace.dir}/${project.name}">
<include name="*.jar"/>
</fileset>
</copy>
</target>
<target name="generateBuildScript">
<eclipse.buildScript elements="plugin@${project.name}"
buildDirectory="${workspace.dir}"
baseLocation="${eclipse.dir}"
configInfo="linux,gtk,win32,win32,x86"/>
</target>
</project>
```

Expecting build.xml to be generated Please Guide me

When I run above script

```
$java -jar {$Eclipse.Dir}/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -buildfile <Project_path>\mybuild.xml
```

I nothing is happening on build success.

Comment: formatted and grammar corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have found the answer may help some new bees like me..

```
<project name="com.foo.poo"  xmlns='antlib:org.apache.tools.ant'>
... 
</project>
```

As there is no default set, it is not generating the required jar file so
modified only the first line as

```
<project name="com.foo.poo" default="build.plugin" xmlns='antlib:org.apache.tools.ant'>
...
</project>
```

now the required jar is generated under plugin folder and even copied to plugin folder of eclipse.
baseLocation : Target Plugins Directory absolute path.
buildDirectory: Absolute path to the plugin folder in which the Plugin Project is  present.

Comment: Now in the build.xml (that is generated from scrip)t is missing only some of the plugin's path                                                                                              Ex: <pathelement path="../eclipse/plugin/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.104.2.v20160212-1350.jar"/> is missing in build.xml.... any clues to solve this missing bundles..(the same is present in trhe build.xml whinch is generated from PDE tool in eclipse)

Comment: The Problem is solved now. It was because of system specific configation that i had done. so removed, configInfo="linux,gtk,win32,win32,x86" this element from the script.